# moving the UIImageView from the main view to another

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, pass-data

my code works fine in choosing the picture from the gallery and display it in the same view,
what am stuck into now, is transferring that UIImageView chosen to the next activity when "next" button is clicked

here is the code that opens the gallery

```
@IBAction func gallery(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.PhotoLibrary) != nil {
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

this is the code that displays the image in the same view

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage 
        imageChosen.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit 
        imageChosen.image = chosenImage 
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) 

    }
```

now after the UIImageView saved in the imageChosen, here is the code am using to pass that image to the next view

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var pass:postView = segue.destinationViewController as! postView
    if(segue.identifier == "next"){
        pass.imgv.image = imageChosen.image
    }
}
```

this line of code that causes the program to crash

```
pass.imgv.image = imageChosen.image
```

the imgv in the second view is declared like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgv: UIImageView!
```

what am i doing wrong here, please direct me

Comment: why not - `pass.imgv = imageChosen`?

Comment: @the_UB when i try this, the app doesn't crash, but the image is not passed, it doesn't show in the other view

Comment: and this `@IBOutlet weak var imgv: UIImage!` and `pass.imgv= imageChosen.image` ?

Comment: @the_UB i will try it now, just one moment

Comment: @the_UB same, the app doesn't crash, but the image is not passed

Comment: I wrote wrong code,try @muku answer.

Comment: @the_UB , i tried it, i wrote a comment of the problem that shows me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot set data in a view which is not rendered yet . So pass image to second view and set that Image to ImageView in secondView's viewDidLoad**

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "next" {
            var pass:second = segue.destinationViewController as! second
            pass.currentImage=myImageView.image;
        }
    }
```

//Second view

```
class second: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tempImgView: UIImageView!
    var currentImage:UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if((currentImage) != nil){
            tempImgView.image=currentImage;
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the `UIImageView` directly in second View Controller. Instead create variable `UIImage` in second View Controller and assign your selected `UIImage` to it. Later in `viewdidload` of second View Controller set the `UIImageView`.

First View

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let pass:postView = segue.destinationViewController as! postView
    if(segue.identifier == "next"){
        pass.tempImage = imageChosen.image
    }
}
```

Second View

```
@IBOutlet weak var imgv: UIImageView!
var tempImage:UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.imgv.image=tempImage
}
```

Comment: When i add this line in the second view var tempImage:UImage it tells me, use of undeclared type UIImage

Comment: do i have to implement an interface or something?

Comment: sorry, thanks its working, but when i click next, the app crashes

Comment: when it crashes, it takes me to this line of code pass.tempImage = imageChosen.image and tells me thread 1: breakpoint 2.1

Comment: check if if image is not nil or not in condition.Check u have properly connected the segue or not

Comment: when i checked if the image is nil or not, the still crashed, but the difference is not it takes me to different breakpoint, does it mean that the image is nil?

Comment: first chck the segue is working or not by commenting the line of setting the image in both the file.If it is proper then `NSLog' the image is it nil or not

Answer (score 0):

You are using weak reference for image view and trying to get it in other controllers . do as following .

@IBOutlet Strong var imgv: UIImageView

Secondly your way of fetching view controller wrong ... Try it as following

```
if segue.identifier == "ShowCounterSegue"
{
    if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? OtherViewController{
        destinationVC.numberToDisplay = counter
     }
 }
```

Comment: Strong is not identified !!, when i try to put it, the compiler doesn't recognise it

Comment: try to just pass uiimage and set to uiimageview.image in viewdidload of destination controller

Answer (score 0):

1. In the PostView, just create variable like `var img: UIImage!`
2. Replace this line `pass.imgv.image = imageChosen.image` with `pass.img = imageChosen.image`
3. In viewDidLoad() of PostView, add this line, `imgv.image = image`

We can not set properties of `IBOutlets` of secondView from the firstView, because IBOutlets of ViewController **will get memory after execution of `viewDidLoad()`**

So you have to create appropriate data variable to pass data to IBOutlet.

Here is the example code.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewInput: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        //check the condition for your segue.identifier, if any

        var destination : NewViewContrller! = segue.destinationViewController as NewViewContrller ;

        if let image = imageViewInput?.image {
            destination.outputImage = image;
        }
    }
}


class NewViewContrller: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outputImageView: UIImageView!
    var outputImage: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if let image = outputImage {
            outputImageView.image = image;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did it, still crashes, when it crashes, it takes me to this line of code pass.img = imageChosen.image and tells me thread 1: breakpoint 2.1

Comment: remove this line pass.imgv.image = imageChosen.image, add this line pass.img = imageChosen.image

have you created "var img: UIImage!" in PostView ?

Comment: yes i did, as you said above, the problem still the same, O_o

Comment: what is the problem ? I mean app crashes or anyother ?

Comment: the app still crashes

Comment: this line pass.img = imageChosen.image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78285/discussion-between-hitendra-hckr-and-aryam-saleh).